# Italics in links loses the link color on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, mobile-web

If italics are used inside link text, at least on MSO, the mobile site gives the italicized text the normal black color, instead of the yellow link color.

For example, `[yellow _black_ yellow](http://www.example.com)` ( [yellow *black* yellow](http://www.example.com) ) looks like

> [yellow](http://www.example.com) *black* [yellow](http://www.example.com)

on mobile, though the entire text is linkified.

Minor bug, but it does look strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed some time back because I can't repro (and I can see a specific entry in the CSS file...). Marking as completed.